# How to deploy a rails app to heroku using C9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, c9.io

I am trying to deploy my rails app to heroku. However, it seems that there is a long process to do. I have to change my db but I do not know how! I also want to know how to push to heroku please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in Michael Hartl's tutorial where there is section on [deploying to Heroku](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-deploying).
Remember that you will need Git before deploying to Heroku. There is good info on that in same tutorial [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-version_control). 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Read this instruction https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

I usually create a Git repo on GitHub or BitBucket and push my Rails project there. Then I go to Heroku website, manually create a new project there (in a dashboard) - and right after that step Heroku provides a detailed list of the Git commands describing how to pull your code from, say, GitHub.

After that you need to run migrations on Heroku - you can do that on your local machine in the console window - but you need to install Heroku CLI (locally) first.

That's it basically. After that Heroku starts your app automatically.

It is not required for you to deploy your code on GitHub or BitBucket. After you init a Git repo locally, you can directly push to Heroku Git. But I prefer use BitBucket as a convenient storage additionally.